# Best algorithm possible to search for a letter in a string and put a ' before the letter efficiently?

Tags: java, algorithm

i need to search in the thousands strings of a array for the character `'`. If i find the character `'`, then, i must put another character `'` before it. Like this: `''`

For example, imagine that i have a 1000 strings on this array:  `List <String> strings.` For example, this is one of my strings:

```
"I have some Levi's shoes."
```

The algorithm must transform the string into: `"I have some Levi''s shoes."`

I must check all the thousands of strings of my array `strings`

Wich is the best efficient way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to iterate over the string in your array, and use [`replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) on each, assigning the results back into the array.

Answer (score 3):

For a single string:

```
myString = myString.replace("'", "''");
```

For a List of strings:

```
for(int i=0;i<myList.size();i++){
    myList.put(i, myList.get(i).replace("'", "''"));
}
```

As Jon Skeet pointed out, `replace` is better than `replaceAll` because you don't have to compile and run a regex for a simple character sequence.

Comment: I'd suggest using `replace` instead of `replaceAll`, to avoid using a regex when it's really not useful here.

Comment: This will also turn double ' into quad ' - which may or may not be part of the requirement.

Comment: @JonSkeet I would have, but java's `String.replace()` only accepts single `char` for both arguments.  For improved performance you'd have to implement your own `replace` method.

Comment: @bdares: No it doesn't, there's a `replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replaceAll` method or `replace`. It simply iterate over String and replace characters.Both of this method compile `regex` and use `StringBuffer`. You don't need regex in you case. Probably you can slightly boost it with your implementation, you don't need regex, you can try `StringBuilder` instead, it's not synchronized.

Comment: `replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)` does *not* use a regex.

Answer (score 1):

You are essentially doing a worst case text search -- that being a single character. I think the only way to get a real speedup is to divide the work and use more threads to do it faster. Multi-core CPU or GPU can really speed up your search, and I know there are Java bindings / libraries for both.

Answer (score 0):

try [StringUtils.replace(String str, String searchChars, String replaceChars)](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#replace%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) (apache commons)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but that method doesn't do what the OP needs. You cannot use it to replace one character by two. You probably meant [replace](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#replace(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) instead

Comment: I downvoted, on the basis that adding a dependency on apache commons for a method that is available in the standard class library (on String, no less) is a bad idea.

Comment: you are right,  take it as a option how to solve the problem, not to be best solution / view of adding dependency, but more secure in a view of testing (null checks etc)